# How to reproduce missing Qt plugin problem on dev machine?

Tags: c++, c, qt, plugins, qt4

I'm trying to deploy my Qt application that relies heavily on SQLite database via Qt's QSQLite plugin. My program runs perfectly fine in the release build on the development machine, but fails utterly to find QSQLite plugin on any machine that has no Qt installed. My problem is similar to the one in these questions:

[QT sqlite deploy exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612736/qt-sqlite-deploy-exe)

[Which Qt DLL's should I copy to make my program stand-alone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614554/which-qt-dlls-should-i-copy-to-make-my-program-stand-alone)

Also, advice on these pages didn't work for me, I copied qsqlite4.dll to all of plugins/, plugins/sqldrivers/ and sqldrivers/ subdirectories, added "addLibraryPath (".");" into my program and it still doesn't work. Static linking is a bad option (we are actually deploying a set of apps and a library).

But my question is not about making it work. It's about making it NOT work on my dev machine. I don't have time (and a windows distro on my hands) to install a virtual machine. So every now and then I need to bother my colleague to let me use her computer for 5 minutes, so that I can copy couple of files, run my program and embarass myself :(

My dev machine is MS Windows XP, with Qt 4.7. App currently resides far away from Qt, Qt libraries are copied to the same dir. Also, I can't find %QTDIR% in environment variables.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Virtual box or VMware's free edition.
Install a mimimal windows system (you don't have to activate it)
Set it so that changes aren't committed to disk

Test your installs there, testing install/dependancy issues on a dev machine is never going to work.

Comment: Actually, you can force Qt not to look for plugins in its own directories with QCoreApplication::setLibraryPath(). Still, I guess, you're right, VM is always the best option.

Comment: In the long run a dev machine will always bite you - a debug dll, copies of earlier SDKs, some symlink or alias = "Well it works on my machine"

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a qt.conf file with your distributable pointing to the plugins?

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qt-conf.html

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/deployment-plugins.html

Comment: I didn't yet try with qt.conf file. Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: +1, using `addLibraryPath` didn't work, but a qt.conf file did!

Answer (score 1):

Does my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047366/qt-dll-deployment-on-windows) help you? See also the link to the Qt documentation.

Comment: That's where I deploy them. But alas, no. Problem temporarily solved by copying qsqlite.dll to C:\Qt\very\long\path\sqldrivers\qsqlite.dll. I know it's lame :(